# Upload/resize image via Ajax on button click, not submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this HTML form that works currently.  It lets you choose an image and it uploads to my server (changing it to have a max height or width of 200) and then displays the image back on the form to show the user...

```
 <div id="preview"><img id="image" src="no-image.jpg" /></div>
 <form id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
    <div id="err"></div>
```

Here is the Jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         url: "upload-image-ajax.php",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
   beforeSend : function()
   {
    //$("#preview").fadeOut();
    $("#err").fadeOut();
   },
   success: function(data) {
    if(data=='invalid file') {
     // invalid file format.
     $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
    } else {
     // view uploaded file.
     $("#image").attr('src', data);
    /* $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();*/
     $("#form")[0].reset(); 
    }
      },
     error: function(e) 
      {
    $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
      }          
    });
 }));
});
```

And here is the PHP the Jquery calls...

```
<?php
require_once("includes/session.php");
$poolid=strtolower($_SESSION['poolid']); //lowercase it first so we get exact matches
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
$path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory

if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
 $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

 // get uploaded file's extension
 $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


//checking if image exists
    if(file_exists("uploads/".$poolid.".png")) {
         unlink("uploads/".$poolid.".png");
    }


 // check's valid format
 if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions))  { 
        //re-size the image and make it a PNG before sending to server
        $final_image = $poolid. ".png";
        $path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 
        $size = getimagesize($tmp);
        $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
        if( $ratio > 1) {
            $width = 200;
            $height = 200/$ratio;
        }
        else {
            $width = 200*$ratio;
            $height = 200;
        }
        $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp));
        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
        imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagepng($dst, $path); // adjust format as needed
        imagedestroy($dst);

        echo $path ."?".rand(1,32000);


 } else {
      echo 'invalid file';
 }
}

?>
```

Again this all works fine when this form is by itself on a page. However, I now want this Image Upload area to be part of a much larger form. I tried adding the exact HTML inside another larger form and as you might have guessed, when I click "upload" to upload the image, it tries to submit the larger form.

I would like it to simply upload/resize the image without submitting the larger form, display the image back to the user and let them continue filling out other form inputs.

I tried removing the form elements (so there was no more nesting of form tags), so the HTML was reduced to this (notice I changed the input type of "submit" to now be "button")...

```
<div id="preview"><img id="image" src="no-image.jpg" /></div>

  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="Upload">

    <div id="err"></div>
```

Then in the Jquery, I removed the .on submit stuff and replaced it with .click, since I just want this image stuff to happen on click, not on any type of submit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#button").click(function(){
    var imageData = new FormData();
    imageData.append('image', $('#uploadImage')[0].files[0]);

    //Make ajax call here:
    $.ajax({
          url: 'upload-image-ajax.php',
          type: 'POST',
          processData: false, // important
          contentType: false, // important
          dataType : 'json',
          data: imageData,
          beforeSend : function()  {
            $("#err").fadeOut();
            alert('hi');
           },
       success: function(result) {
           alert('succ');
            if(result=='invalid file') {
             // invalid file format.
             $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
            } else {
             // view uploaded file.
             $("#image").attr('src', result);
            /* $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();*/
             $("#form")[0].reset(); 
            }
          },
         error: function(result)  {
             alert(result.responseText);
              $("#err").html(result).fadeIn();
          }      
     });
   });

  });
```

Again, I am reading about the data and dataType settings at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, but I cannot grasp it for the life of me (no experience with JSON probably isn't helping me).

Can someone please speak towards the var imageData and .append part of my new Jquery, as I assume that must be where things are going off the rails.  As is often the case, this seems like it should be super easy to accomplish since I have it working fine on its own, but it's driving me insane.

Comment: You are on the right track. In the success callback, `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` to see what the ajax response is bringing back. Are there any errors? Edit: Also, try printing the $_POST data to make sure it is being passed across as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I updated the Jquery above with where I have it now for testing.  It's doing the "error" part and in the console it says "Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}".   I'm not sure how to print the $_POST data, but I'm pretty sure that's the problem (i.e. it's not being passed across as I'd expect, like you said.  Can you help me with how to do that?  Which file do I print the $_POST data in?

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in your JavaScript at this line: `imageData.append('name_of_picture_file', $('#uploadImage').prop('files')[0]);` you have to use `imageData.append('name_of_picture_file', $('#uploadImage')[0].files[0]);`. and also if you are giving this name `name_of_picture_file` to your parameter, then in your _php_ you have to use `$img = $_FILES['name_of_picture_file']['name'];` instead of `$img = $_FILES['image']['name'];`

Comment: Check what he said, but in order to output the post data you'd have to `print_r($_POST);` in the ajax file.

Comment: Thank you both.  I updated the last JQUERY snippet above.  At this point, the image is uploading to the server (like I want) but it's still returning as an error.   In the JQUERY above, see how i have "alert(result.responseText);"?  That alerts the exact text that I am hoping is returned (the new image name).  So I'm thoroughly confused why it's coming back as "error" and not as "success".  I have to be missing something obvious. Anything jump out as still wrong?

Comment: FYI, "uploads/11169j5ktc.png?5198" is an example of what is being returned, which again, is exactly what I want. So not sure why it's an "error" and not "success"

Comment: Get rid of `dataType : 'json'` in your jQuery. This tells jQuery to expect a json response from your server, but your server is just responding with plain text. If you want your server to respond with json, add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before you echo a response.

Comment: That was it!  Embarassing that it was something that dumb, but really appreciate you letting me know.  Was really driving me nuts. Thanks so much to all three of you for your input!